# 'xz -d' vs. `unxz`

Tags: scripting, xz

Why is `xz -d` preferred over `unxz` when writing scripts?

From the `man` page for `xz 5.1.0alpha`:

> When writing scripts that need to decompress files, it is recommended to always use the name `xz` with appropriate arguments (`xz -d` or `xz -dc`) instead of the names `unxz` and `xzcat`.

Comment: Unless Lasse Collin answers the question here, I think any answers would just be guesses...

Answer (score 1):

`unxz` and`xzcat` are symlinks to `xz` (`xz`, like many programs behaves differently depending on what program name it is called as).

It's possible for only the `xz` binary to be installed - the symlinks may not have been created when `xz` was installed, or they might have been removed later.  `xz` will work just fine without the symlinks, but the symlinks won't work without `xz`.

so, the recommendation is to use the binary that is guaranteed to be there if `xz` is installed rather than symlinks which might not be.